# Selecting cells with similar value and then renaming the texts chronologically

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[image]

I would like to automatically rename cells with the same value. For example, in a range I have selected, there are 3 cells with "stackoverflow". The desired output would be to select those cells then change the text to something like this

stackoverflow_1
stackoverflow_2
stackoverflor_3

I've done the renaming part, but what I'm having trouble with is how you could select similar cells in a range. Here is what I have so far. Hopefully I could create a for loop or do while loop for this.

```
Sub rename()
num = WorksheetFunction.CountA(Selection)

Do While num <> 0

With Selection
    .Cells(num, 1).Value = Selection.Cells(num, 1) & "_" & num
End With
num = num - 1
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: the `num` variable is the range selected with the same texts inside

Comment: Do all the selected cells contain the same value, or only some of them?  Are you looking for a specific string?

Comment: You can use [.Find and .FindNext](http://www.siddharthrout.com/index.php/2018/01/05/find-and-findnext-in-excel-vba/) with a counter to rename the cells?

Comment: So in my excel, I have 1500 rows in column A, all containing pipe line names. There are occurrences where pipe line names are repeated. So in those cases where there are repeating names, I have to change those by adding "_1" "_2" "_3" and so on until all similar cells have been named like that. @TimWilliams

Comment: @TimWilliams I added a photo in the question to show you exactly what I'm trying to achieve

Comment: @SiddharthRout I've added a photo so show what i'm trying to achieve

Comment: Oh then you do not need vba. Posted a reply. you may have to refresh the page to see it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's one approach:

```
Dim dict As Object, c As Range
Set dict = CreateObject("scripting.dictionary")
For Each c in Selection.Cells
    v = c.Value
    If Len(v) > 0 Then
        'Is count > 1 or was it >1 at some point? 
        If dict.Exists(v) Or Application.CountIf(Selection, v) > 1 Then
            dict(v) = dict(v) + 1
            c.Value = v & "_" & dict(v)
        End If   
    End If 
Next c
```

Comment: This actually works. Only with one problem, the last cell is not renamed.Like if I have to rename 5 cells, it adds "_1" until "_4", and then ends.

Comment: I solved it. I just change the "1" to "0" in the line `Application.Countif(Selection, v) > 1 Then` THANK YOU SO MUCH!!

Comment: No I have a logic flaw in there - forgot the CountIf would change as the cells get modified.  If you just change it to >0 that doesn't really fix it since that will always be true...    OK fixed it I think...

Answer (score 2):

There is no need of VBA unless you specifically want to use it. Use the below formula

```
=IF(AND(COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1)=1,A1<>A2),A1,A1&COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1))
```

[image]

Ensure that the data is sorted.

Without sorting you can use this formula (Courtsey @JvdV)

```
=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$17,A1)=1,A1,A1&"_"&COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1))
```

Comment: Alternatively (without sorting): `=IF(COUNTIF($A$1:$A$17,A1)=1,A1,A1&"_"&COUNTIF($A$1:A1,A1))`

Comment: nice one @JvdV :) Included it in the post above

Comment: Will use this as well. Thanks guys!